# web API versioning using namespace

Tags: asp.net-web-api, url-routing, versioning

I am trying to implement ASP.net web API versioning using URL(namespace) techniques.
I have existing controller say Roles controller. I am able to access it via route .../ API/roles.
Now I have added one more controller with same name Roles but in different folder say V1.
I added route for this new controller and I am able to access it via .../API/V1/roles. 
But now when I am trying to access my old route I.e. .../API/roles. I am getting error as multiple controller found. One controller in folder V1 and another in folder controllers.
Can anyone help me in figuring out this issue. How to fallback the existing routes.
If I add another folder v2 and try to access roles controller over there its working fine.
But for existing controller which is placed directly in Controllers folder its not working.
Any help is appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: See my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/28444921/853005

Comment: possible duplicate of [Web API versioning configuration](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23751509/web-api-versioning-configuration)