# web api call route matching

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have api call route defines as this

```
routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "VisitGetByIdApi",
                routeTemplate: "api/v1/visits/{id}",
                defaults: new { Controller = "Visits", Action = "GetById" },
                constraints: new { id = @"\d*", httpMethod = new HttpMethodConstraint(new[] { "GET", "POST" }) }
                );
```

I am trying to call web api from my .js file via ajax but I keep getting 404 error, what is the rigt way of calling.

```
self.GetVisitById = function () {
        debugger;
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "/api/v1/visits",
            data: {
                id: self.Id()
            },
            traditional: true,
            success: function (data) {
                debugger;
                return data;
            },
            error: function (data) {
                debugger;
            }
        });
    }
```

Message: "No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI 'http://localhost:1059/api/v1/visits?id=5217'."
MessageDetail: "No type was found that matches the controller named 'v1'."

Comment: Looks like it expects something like `/api/v1/visits/333` and you're sending to something like `/api/v1/visits?id=333` which is not the same

Comment: See this post

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23751509/web-api-versioning-configuration